# Dynamic Class loading in java

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I have some weird requirment I need to load a class dynamically,

here I have an `Interface`

```
    public interface House
    {
       public Object loadHouseModel(String type);
       public Object loadHouseSpace(String type); 
     }
```

now the desired class will implement this interface

```
     public class DuplexHouse implements House 
     {
        public Object loadHouseModel(String type)
        {
             ///Method body goes here
        }
        public Object loadHouseSpace(String type)
         {
             ///Method body goes here
         }
      }
```

Now my requirement is that I need to load `DuplexHouse` or whatever the class which implements `House`

Requirment is that `DuplexHouse` class name I will get it from properties and All I know is The class name I get will Implement the `House` Interface. 
so my propertie looks like this
          `type_house=xx.xx.xxx.DuplexHouse,xx.xx.xx.TruplexHouse,..etc`

Based on the type of House I need to load corresponding house object

So in my main class 
           `Class cl = Class.forName(xx.xxx.xxx.DuplexHouse);`
My requirment is I want `House` Instance which internally holds `DuplexHouse` object
How can I do that ??

Comment: What do you need to do with the `Class` object?  Is anything preventing you from just instantiating `House house = new DuplexHouse()` ?

Comment: use generics for anything that implements interface use like `ClassName<T extends House>`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can not Instantiate `House` with `DuplexHouse` cause `DuplexHouse` is unknow that time I take this class name from property. All I know is that `DuplexHouse` implements `House`

Comment: Honestly, you have the interface.  Why do you care about the concrete type?  The concrete type only serves to implement that interface.  Otherwise, you're stuck using `instanceof` or a variant of it as suggested in an answer.

Comment: Try method `Class.newInstance()`

Comment: So why can't you just do `House house = (House)Class.forName("xxx.xxx.xxx.DuplexHouse").newInstance();`?

Comment: You haven't quite answered my question.  Why do you ***need*** it?

Comment: @Makoto Because the name of DuplexHouse is unknown at compile time. It will be read from a property file. The asker has said that a few times already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First do `Class.forName`. This will give you the `DuplexHouse` class in the form of `Class<?>`. On that, do `newInstance()`. It will give you the instance of `DuplexHouse` in the form of an `Object`. Cast this to `House` and you have your `DuplexHouse` instance in the form of `House`.

This assumes (1) the DuplexHouse class in in the class path (2) DuplexHouse constructor takes zero arguments.

Answer (score -1):

@Babel I could not quite understand your question, but you're able to check if an object is an instance of any class or interface with the `instanceof` keyword.

For example

`boolean isLion = felineAnimal instanceof Lion
boolean isWolf = canineAnimal instanceof Wolf`